# How to convert a function to a Pandas UDF in PySpark?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a function in Python I would like to adapt to PySpark. I am pretty new to PySpark so finding a way to implement this - whether with a UDF or actually in PySpark is posing a challenge.

Essentially, it performs a series of `numpy` calculations on a grouped by dataframe. I am not entirely sure the best way to do this in PySpark

Python code:

```
data = [
    [1, "a", 10, 23, 33],
    [1, "b", 11, 25, 34],
    [1, "c", 12, 35, 35],
    [1, "d", 13, 40, 36],
    [2, "e", 14, 56, 38],
    [2, "g", 14, 56, 39],
    [2, "g", 16, 40, 38],
    [2, "g", 19, 87, 90],
    [3, "a", 20, 12, 90],
    [3, "a", 21, 45, 80],
    [3, "b", 21, 45, 38],
    [3, "c", 12, 45, 67],
    [3, "d", 18, 45, 78],
    [3, "d", 12, 78, 90],
    [3, "d", 8, 85, 87],
    [3, "d", 19, 87, 89],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["id", "sub_id", "sub_sub_id", "value_1", "value_2"])
df
```

```
grouped_df = df.groupby(["id", "sub_id", "sub_sub_id"])

aggregated_df = grouped_df.agg(
            {
                "value_1": ["mean", "std"],
                "value_2": ["mean", "std"],
            }
        ).reset_index()
```

```
for value in ["value_1", "value_2"]:
    aggregated_df[f"{value}_calc"] = np.maximum(
        aggregated_df[value]["mean"]
        - grouped_df[value].min().values,
        grouped_df[value].max().values
        - aggregated_df[value]["mean"],
    )
```

I was trying to perform a `Window` function with the already grouped and aggregated Spark Dataframe, but I am pretty sure this is not the best way to do this.

```
test = aggregated_sdf.withColumn(
    "new_calculated_value",
    spark_fns.max(
        spark_fns.expr(
            "ave_value_1" - spark_fns.min(spark_fns.collect_list("ave_value_1"))
        ),
        (
            spark_fns.expr(
                spark_fns.max(spark_fns.collect_list("ave_value_1")) - "ave_value_1"
            )
        ),
    ).over(Window.partitionBy("id", "sub_id", "sub_sub_id"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing the calculations during the aggregation, similar to what you did in the pandas code. The equivalent of `np.maximum` should be `F.greatest`. `F.max` is an aggregate function which gets the maximum in a column, while `F.greatest` is **not** an aggregate function, and gets the maximum of several columns along a single row.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.groupby("id", "sub_id", "sub_sub_id").agg(
    F.mean('value_1').alias('ave_value_1'), 
    F.mean('value_2').alias('ave_value_2'), 
    F.greatest(
        F.mean('value_1') - F.min('value_1'), 
        F.max('value_1') - F.mean('value_1')
    ).alias('value_1_calc'), 
    F.greatest(
        F.mean('value_2') - F.min('value_2'), 
        F.max('value_2') - F.mean('value_2')
    ).alias('value_2_calc')
)
```